# Creating HTML Tags in VIM

Tags: vim

I am trying to keep my VIM plugin use to a minimum (call me crazy) and I came across a great VIM script that does what I need quite well.

`imap <C-t> <></><Esc>5hdiw3lpT>i`

It works great for creating a `<div></div>` however, I am currently working in Vuetify and there are tags like `<v-img></v-img>` and the letters before the dash gets missed. I get something like: `v-<img></img>`.

Any idea what adjustments I can make to my script that will use the letter before the dash as part of the tag?

Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change a few things…

If you add `-` to `:help 'isfname'` the `diw` part of your mapping will cover the whole `v-img`.

Here is a version of your mapping that doesn't rely on counting characters:

```
inoremap <C-t> <C-o>diw<<C-r>"></<C-r>"><C-o>T>
```

- `<C-o>` leaves insert mode only for one normal mode command, without triggering autocomands,
- `diw` cuts the word under the cursor to the unnamed register, `"`,
- `<` inserts `<`,
- `<C-r>"` inserts the content of register `"`,
- `></` inserts `></`,
- `<C-r>"` inserts the content of register `"`,
- `>` inserts `>`,
- `<C-o>` leaves insert mode only for one normal mode command, without triggering autocomands,
- `T>` moves the cursor between the opening and closing tags.

Reference:

```
:help i_ctrl-o
:help i_ctrl-r
:help ""
:help T
```

Comment: i must be doing something wrong, I'm seeing the same issue as before using your mappings.

Comment: Did you change `&iskeyword` as suggested?

Comment: I'm afraid I'm going to need additional hand-holding here. When I enter `:help isfname` in the command line I'm taken to a file I cannot change. 

Could you be more specific of what I need to do? Sorry, I'm quite new to VIM

Comment: Thank you I figured it out. Your answer is correct and you really helped my VIM knowledge grow by leaps and bounds.